# Skip every other beat from a song

Tags: audio, mp3

There's a popular meme in which a song is modified in such a way that every other beat is removed from it.

Example: [Smooth Criminal But Every Other Beat is Missing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLvDnRU_ajk)

Is there a software that can do this automatically for any song?

- It should be able to do this automatically, i.e. takes in an MP3 file, and outputs the modified MP3 file.
- Optionally let you configure the beat parameter (i.e. which n<sup>th</sup> beat to skip)
- Windows Freeware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://beatmachine.branchpanic.me/
this website lets you remove as many other beats as you want, as well as swap, cut, repeat, silence, and randomize the beats.

Comment: it doesnt work for me. Can you help

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask for help about it.
Try the GitHub repo, https://github.com/beat-machine/beat-machine/discussions